# AWS Lambda cant find address in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

My team member wrote a lambda function that connects to a mem cache in AWS ElastiCache. memjs is a npm package.

```
const memjs = require("memjs");
const client = memjs.Client.create(`${CACHE_ADDRESS}:${CACHE_PORT}`);
```

where CACHE_ADDRESS / CACHE_PORT are environment variables in the lambda.

[image]

My Route53 record routing policy is simple & Type = CNAME and the hosted zone in this example is stackoverflow.com . Leading to the cache_address being myroute53address.stackoverflow.com

[image]

When I test the lambda through postman
it gives me an error

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myroute53address.stackoverflow.com at GetAddrInfoReqWrap

I was wondering if I need to give the Lambda an access policy or something to access that hosted zone?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a missing Security Group.